# Visual Studio 2015 .net core build artifacts not generated

Tags: visual-studio-2015, build, .net-core

I have a problem with my Visual Studio 15. When I am doing a build using the Studio the artifacts are not generated and I always get an error message like: "The application to execute does not exist"

I have created a complete blank .net core console Programing with one Hello World Console.Write. When I running the build I get:

> ------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApp1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ---->--
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

But the dll / exe file is not generated.

If I run the "dotnet build" command everything is working fine.

Comment: VS15 or 2015? VS15 = VS2017 and this is still in RC status  so errors may occur

Comment: 2015 Visual Studio

Comment: reinstall the .net core VS tools again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to magicandre1981. You need to uninstall and reinstall the .net core VS tools and it started working again.

I tried an repair first but this NOT worked out